# cppcms lots of unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, pcre, zlib, cppcms

I am having errors as follows trying to build cppcms.

```
Error   184 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_compile referenced in function "public: void __cdecl booster::regex::assign(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (?assign@regex@booster@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)   C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\pcre_regex.obj
Error   185 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_exec referenced in function "public: bool __cdecl booster::regex::match(char const *,char const *,class std::vector,class std::allocator > > &,int)const " (?match@regex@booster@@QEBA_NPEBD0AEAV?$vector@U?$pair@HH@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@HH@std@@@2@@std@@H@Z)   C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\pcre_regex.obj
Error   186 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_fullinfo referenced in function "public: void __cdecl booster::regex::assign(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (?assign@regex@booster@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)  C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\pcre_regex.obj
Error   187 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_malloc referenced in function "public: __cdecl booster::regex::data::data(struct booster::regex::data const &)" (??0data@regex@booster@@QEAA@AEBU012@@Z)   C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\pcre_regex.obj
Error   188 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_pcre_free referenced in function __catch$??0data@regex@booster@@QEAA@AEBU012@@Z$0   C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\pcre_regex.obj
Error   189 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons referenced in function "public: __cdecl booster::aio::endpoint::endpoint(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (??0endpoint@aio@booster@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z)   C:\Stuff\Development\CPP\cppcms-1.0.2\build\booster\endpoint.obj
```

My environment is Windows 7 64 bit, using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, and CMake 2.8.9.

For everything I compile, I configure CMake to generate solutions for VS2012 to use the 64 bit compiler.  When I do compile the libraries, I compile the release versions.

First I compile Zlib 1.2.7 without a problem.
Second I compile pcre-8.31 without a problem.

Then when it gets time to compile cppcms-1.0.2 I get a bunch or errors as I pointed out before.  When configuring cppcms in CMake, I have my PYTHON 2.7 set, I use

```
 C:/Stuff/Development/CPP/Zlib/zlib-1.2.7/build
```

for my ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR, and just append a /Release/zlibstatic.lib at the end of that and you have the ZLIB library I am using, but I am not sure if I have my PCRE set up correctly.

Being that PCRE has an include and include2 in CMake, I wasn't sure what to put in them so I just did the pcre-8.31 root directory, and the pcre-8.31 build directory.  For PCRE_LIB I use pcre-8.31/build/Release/pcre.lib.

I have deleted all of the build directories for the libraries and started over again even, but I still have these issues and I am not sure what could be causing them.  Later I realized the booster inside of the cppcms build directory also has a solution, so I built that first, which had 3 failed projects, but most succeeded, however it didn't make a difference for cppcms building.

If you have any more questions about what I was doing, please ask and I will edit them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to ask questions about cppcms is in the cppcms mailing list. Sign up here:
https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/cppcms-users

Artyom is providing an excellent support service there. Although he is also a S.O. member, not all cppcms developers are, and many of them also provide help on the mailing list. Overall, you'll get better answers there, especially since the people who are able to answer will more quickly notice your question.